# Unknown column in 'where clause' whereas column exist

Tags: php, mysql

i m trying to update a column sort where value = 0 but its showing me this error

> Unknown column 'sort' in 'where clause'

i am using the following query

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `category` SET `sort`='1' WHERE `sort`='0'")
```

the sort colum is exist on the database but i dont know y its not updating

Comment: Are you sure that table `category` exist ?

Comment: ys its exist also the column sort is also exist

Comment: if you have access to the command line, login into your mysql db and do a `describe category` then show us the output.

Comment: your query should work. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e5ac/1)

Comment: Check While Connecting to Database have select Database which contain <b>category</b> with <b>sort</b> field table.<br/>
Check `mysql_select_db()` function.<br/>
Your SQL seems right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is correct. That would mean that your observation - that column `sort` exists in table `category` in the *currently selected DB* - is incorrect.

Comment: ahh yes. thanks man it solved actually i was connected with a same database i didn't checked that